# Playing sound samples on the iPhone

Tags: ios, audio, playback

I've reached the point where i want to play some samples in my game/app. My instinct says use openAL ... I will have the situation where I will need to play multiple samples at once (however no more than 2 or 3) and the samples will be short (2 or 3 seconds).

My question is what is the best way of playing samples on the iPhone given that criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a piece of sample code I am using:

**1st option:**

I defined this in my .h file

```
SystemSoundID topClick;
```

And in my .m file I firest load the sound (aiff file):

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *topClickFile = [bundle pathForResource:@"top_click" ofType:@"aiff"];
```

Then, when I want to play the sound, I use:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(topClick);
```

**2nd option:**

You could also use the AVAudioPlayer (available since firmware 2.2 I think):

```
NSString *graffitiSprayFile = [bundle pathForResource:@"sound_effect" ofType:@"aiff"];
AVAudioPlayer* sprayAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:graffitiSprayFile] error:NULL];
sprayAudio.delegate = self;
[sprayAudio prepareToPlay];
[sprayAudio setNumberOfLoops:999];
```

The first option is very usable for relatively short sound effect.

Comment: Just a point of information - AVAudioPlayer can play multiple caf, aiff, wav files but only one mp3 can play at a time (so don't use mp3 for game effects).

Comment: Also setting the number of loops to -1 will make the sample repeat forever.

Comment: Is a call to AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID required?

Comment: Can I ask a question? how can I maximize the volum of the sound by code? thanks a lot