# record audio and play on iphone

Tags: audio

Can anyone please provide any sample code to record audio and then play on iphone ?

Thanks in advance,
abc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing sound samples on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714618/playing-sound-samples-on-the-iphone)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I record audio on iPhone with AVAudioRecorder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPhone_with_AVAudioRecorder

It provides some simple sample code.  It worked for me.